# Ideas for enterprise configuration

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, app-config, enterprise

I'm in the middle of building a very large enterprise application.

I have main machine that controls all the other machines.

now I'm about to start writing some admin capabilities as configuration manager.

in each server I have some services and each service has some variable that I would like to be configurable.

I thought maybe to add an xml configuration file to each service (it would be read when the service starts up) and when I will do configuration distribution I will change that xml file with the new configuration data.

I will also need a way to restart the service in order to get the new configuration.

My question is:

Is there any better way do accomplish enterprise configuration ability?
if my Idea is good any tips and improvement will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

I decide to create config file (xml) for each service.

I create FileWatcher that listen for ant change in the file.

in order to set a new configuration I used XmlSerializer .

because of the change FilwWatcher Change event raise and I deserialize the configuration file and set the new configuration to the service.